# Java programming threads and applets

Tags: java, multithreading, applet

I'm trying to write a java applet program that creates a thread and does two things:

1. Print numbers in the normal flow of execution
2. repaint the applet in thread

please take a look at the following code

```
public class Sample extends applet implements Runnable
{
    Thread t=new Thread(this);
    int y=500;

    public void init()
    {
        t.start();
        for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(i);
            try {
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            repaint()
            if(y==100) y=500; else y-=100;
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.fillOval(50,y,50,50);
    }

}
```

I wrote this code thinking that a black ball will move up and down and at the same time prints numbers but when i run it it prints numbers and the ball doesn't move until it prints all the numbers. I can't understand why.

Comment: You shouldn't use applets or write threaded code until you understand Java.

Comment: You shouldn't write applets at all. They are **dead** technology; unless your company orders you to use applets you really really do not want to learn about them - as this knowledge is of almost zero value nowadays.

Comment: If you program doesn't do what you expect you should use the debugger in your IDE to step through the code. This is what a debugger is for.

Comment: Everyone i get what you are trying to say but is there anything wrong in the code.. i mean why doesn't it create two threads nd do what two things

Comment: I don't know AWT or Swing very well, so I don't know whether it is safe to call `repaint()` from an arbitrary thread.  Most Swing/AWT methods are only allowed to be called from the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT), but there are a few exceptions, and repaint() might be one of those.

Comment: thanks james large but when i use a Thread.currentThread() to display all threads i get three different threads..  Do you know why?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Without knowing where you called Thread.currentThread() _from_, it's kind of hard to guess why it returns what it returns.  I don't know how many threads you should expect an applet to have (as Jägermeister said, applets are a dead technology), but if that code were part of a desktop application, then there would be at least a main() thread, plus the Event Dispatch Thread, plus the thread that you created, plus various other threads that are needed by the JVM.  Only the first three would be executing your code though.

Comment: Assuming that it's ok to call repaint() from a non-EDT thread, your example code calls it _extremely fast_.   Again, I don't know AWT/Swing, and so I don't know what it will do when you try to repaint that often, but one thing I would not expect to see is anything "moving" on the screen.  Usually, the right way to animate something is to drive the animation with a `javax.swing.Timer` or something like.

Answer (score 0):

You do your printing from the `.init()` method.  Like I said in comments, above, I don't know much about AWT/Swing, and I know even less about the `Applet` class, but maybe you should do your printing from `.start()` instead.

The Javadoc says that `.init()` is called to "inform the applet that it has been loaded," and `start()` is called "to inform the applet that it should start running."

Like I also said in the comments, above.  I would use a timer to drive the animation, and not explicitly create a thread.

I probably would use a timer to drive the counting too:  I'd write a `.start()` method that just starts the two timers and returns.